# ASP.NET Chart add percentage next to the number

Tags: asp.net, charts, series

I have a chart control that is displaying columns with values on top (series with labels). Those values come from the database and they are already in the percentage format (i.e.: displaying 12.54 not 0.1254)

I want to add the "%" next to the numbers.

when I try to use the "LabelFormat" property and set it to "P2" i get the numbers like this:

1254.00% !!

I think the P2 is doing some calculations!

I just want to add the "%" symbol next to the number. that's it

can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself! thanks for everything ..

Here is the answer:

in order to just display "%" next to the number, just do the following:

```
Chart1.Series["MySeries"].Label = "#VALY"+"%";
```

OR (for the Y Axis for example:)

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{#}%";
```

This worked fine for me!

Answer (score 3):

Combining Yousi's solution with that of Alex Z

If your value is in decimal format, e.g. 0.14 = 14% then use this markup:

```
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY >
                <LabelStyle Format="{0:p}" />
            </AxisY>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
```

If your value is the actual number you would like to see, just with % after it use this:

```
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY >
                <LabelStyle Format="{#}%" />
            </AxisY>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
```

i.e. If you try the first block of code above and see values like 1,000% where you expect 10% use the second.

Answer (score 2):

The "P" format specifier takes a number and considers it as a percent, so 1 will be translated to 100%. Can't you return the percentage like 0.1254?

Comment: no, I tried that but it's not working properly. since the Y Axis is from 0 to 100 .. all the values then were on the X Axis since they did not exceed 1 !

Comment: I tried doing something else ..

instead of using "LabelFormat" .. i just used "Label" property and set the value to "#PERCENT" .. this worked fine, but i noticed that the numbers changed ! instead of displaying 8.48% , I get 13.99% !

Answer (score 1):

Better to use below to avoid multiplying percentage values by 100

```
   <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY >
                <LabelStyle Format="{p0}" />
            </AxisY>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY >
                <LabelStyle Format="{0:p}" />
            </AxisY>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Its shows percentage like 10.7%

```
                        <asp:Series Name="SatisfiedSeries" BorderWidth="2" Color="#FFC107" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Font="Verdana, 8pt, style=Bold" LabelForeColor="#E0A800" LabelBorderWidth="2" LabelFormat="#.#%"></asp:Series>
```